# rename file name using path info extension with dot

Tags: php

i need new name of file name using pathinfo($url,  PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

this my code

```
$name = "name.txt";
$f = fopen($name, 'r');

$nwname = fgets($f);

fclose($f);

$newfname = $destination_folder .$nwname. pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

output:
1 jpeg

how to make output nospace and write (.) dot before jpeg like this

output:
1.jpeg

thank

Comment: `$nwname. "." . pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"."'

Comment: `$newfname = $destination_folder . trim($nwname) . '.' . pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: sorry this work , iam wrong , output : 1 .jpeg ,, now ho to make this whit nospace ?

Comment: use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to strip leading and trailing spaces

Comment: A variable must have whitespace in it, `var_dump` and see which one does then `trim` it.

Comment: work Fine using 'trim' .thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in comments, here's write up.

The `.` is used for concatenation. So `$variable.$variable` puts the values of the two variables together. `$variable.'.'.$variable` would add a period between the 2 variables. The `trim` function should be used to remove leading and trailing whitespaces from a variable.

Functional demo: https://eval.in/520038

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concatenate strings like below :

```
$newfname = $destination_folder .$nwname.'.'. pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```